# Number Footnote by Verse

Tags: numbering, footnotes

Hello: this is my first time asking a question, please be patient if I do something wrong.  I have a series of questions related to footnote customization; I will try to ask only one at a time.

I am attempting to retype a 1930's era Spanish language bible featuring footnotes.  I am attempting to retain some flavor of the original typesetting, particularly for the footnotes.

Instead of the usual little superscripted number, these footnotes are found at the bottom of the text column cited by the verse number; there is no indication in the verse that there is a footnote.

(For anyone unfamiliar, bibles are frequently organized into three levels: book, chapter, and verse, the last being usually about the length of a short sentence, and preceded by a verse number.  A verse in this sense is not quite the same as a verse of poetry, in terms of formatting.  For now, I am using the 'paragraph' sectioning command to approximate the normal effect.)

I would like to figure out, in the best case, how to automatically renumber footnotes to reflect the verse number, or if that cannot be done, at least how to suppress the little superscript number in both the text body and at the beginning of the footnote, so I can manually type in the verse number.

Here is an example of the desired layout:

SALMO CXVI

1. Alabad al Senor, naciones todas de la tierra: pueblos todos cantad sus alabanzas.
2. Porque su misericordia se ha confirmado sobre nosotros; y la verdad del Senor permanence eternamente.

---

v. 2. Este es un ejemplo del formato de las notas, que, en este caso, refiere al segundo versiculo del dicho salmo.  No hay numeros chiquitos ni en el texto ni en la nota.  La nota simplemente comienza con el numero del versiculo.

**EDIT:** I appear to have made myself hard to understand: apologies!  I am attaching an image showing the relationship between the text, arranged in numbered verses, and the footnotes that belong to them.

[image: Sample showing layout of text with footnotes]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the clarification of the question, I changed substantially the example to adapt better to the desired layout, but the core of the answer is still that you can use `\footnotetext[<mark>]{<text>}` to make a footnote without marks in main text:

However, the  `\piedenota{}` macro defined below write automatically the  `\versiculo` reference, so just use it like a simple `\footnote{}` without optional argument, and you will be free of human mistakes messing with optional arguments.

The rest of the example below are only convenience macros to avoid typing or mimic a bit the main text structure, although  without paying attention to headers margins, etc. Some notes about this off-topic part:

1. I do not see some like a table of contents (ToC) in a Spanish bible from 1975 so I defined  `\libro`, `\capitulo`, `\titulo` in a quick and dirty way. If you will need a ToC or often cross-references to section levels it could be definitively better work with standard sectioning levels (`\part`, `\chapter` and `\section`) and redefine them conveniently. There are many questions about in this site.
2. For the verses (note: in Spanish "versículo", not "verso" like in poems) you can also consider a enumerate list with the `enumitem` package instead of a custom macro (some like  `\begin{enumerate}[wide, label=\textbf{\arabic*}., labelwidth=!, labelindent=\parindent] \item ... \item ... \end{enumerate}` should work for this format) and then use cross-references for the footnote marks.
3. Sorry, the verses are pasted from elsewhere and they are quite different to text of the image, and notes are dummy text,  but without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to start to play is a bit annoying write a whole bible page.

MWE:

> [image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cuted}
\newcounter{versiculo}
\def\libro#1{\addtocounter{part}{1}
\begin{strip}
\centering\textbf{\Large\Roman{part}. \uppercase{#1}}
\end{strip}} 
\def\capitulo{\finversiculo{\addtocounter{chapter}{1}\centering\large
CAPÍTULO \Roman{chapter}\par\medskip}}
\def\titulo#1{{\par{\centering\bfseries #1 \par\medskip}}}
\def\versiculo{\par\addtocounter{versiculo}{1}%
\textbf{\arabic{versiculo}}.~}
\def\piedenota#1{\footnotetext[\value{versiculo}]{#1}}
\def\finversiculo{\setcounter{versiculo}{0}}
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\textbf{v.~\@thefnmark.}~}
\def\@makefntext#1{\parindent1em \@makefnmark #1}

\begin{document}

\libro{Cristo en su vida se muestra dios} 
\capitulo 
\titulo{Cristo, Verbo Eterno de Dios.}

\versiculo  
\piedenota{\textbf{En el principio:} Desde la eternidad. \lipsum*[2]}  
En el principio era el Verbo, y el Verbo era con Dios,
y el Verbo era Dios. 
\versiculo 
\piedenota{\textbf{Estaba\ldots en Dios.} como hijo suyo
coeterno y cosustancial.} 
\versiculo Todas las cosas por él fueron hechas, y sin él nada de lo
que ha sido hecho, fue hecho. 
\versiculo  En él estaba la vida, y la vida era la luz de los hombres. 
\versiculo  La luz en las tinieblas resplandece, y las tinieblas no
prevalecieron contra ella. 
\versiculo  Hubo un hombre enviado de Dios, el cual se llamaba Juan.
\versiculo Este vino por testimonio, para que diese testimonio de la
luz, a fin de que todos creyesen por él. 
\versiculo No era él la luz, sino para que diese testimonio de la luz. 
\versiculo Aquella luz verdadera, que alumbra a todo hombre,
venía a este mundo. 
\versiculo En el mundo estaba, y el mundo por él fue hecho;
pero el mundo no le conoció. 
\versiculo
\piedenota{\textbf{A su propia casa.} etc. }
A lo suyo vino, y los suyos no le recibieron. 
\versiculo Mas a todos los que le recibieron, a los que creen en su
nombre, les dio potestad de ser hechos hijos de Dios. 
\versiculo los cuales no son engendrados de sangre,
ni de voluntad de carne, ni de voluntad de varón, sino de Dios. 
\versiculo Y aquel Verbo fue hecho carne, y habitó entre nosotros
(y vimos su gloria, gloria como del unigénito del Padre),
lleno de gracia y de verdad. 

\titulo{\hfil Testimonios del Bautista}

\versiculo Juan dio testimonio de él, y clamó diciendo: Este es de
quien yo decía: El que viene después de mí, es antes de mí;
porque era primero que yo. 
\versiculo Porque de su plenitud tomamos todos, y gracia sobre gracia. 
\versiculo Pues la ley por medio de Moisés fue dada, pero la gracia y
la verdad vinieron por medio de Jesucristo. 
\versiculo A Dios nadie le vio jamás; el unigénito Hijo, que está en el
seno del Padre, él le ha dado a conocer. 


\hfil\vdots\par\bigskip %  ... rest of chapter 

\capitulo

\titulo{Las bodas de Caná} 

\versiculo Al tercer día se hicieron unas bodas en Caná de Galilea;
y estaba allí la madre de Jesús. 
\versiculo \piedenota{foo bar baz ...}
Y fueron también invitados a las bodas Jesús y sus discípulos. 
\versiculo Y faltando el vino, la madre de Jesús le dijo:
No tienen vino. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you do not have the ñ character in your keyboard, you can type `\~n`  to obtain the correct output  or use a shorcut as Alt+164, AltGr+n,  or Ctrl+Shift+U 00f1, or  something else ... (Sorry,  I cannot be more specific. depends on the OS and editor.)

Comment: Appreciated!  An excellent answer that is, unfortunately, not what I am looking for - apologies for my poor phrasing.  I am looking to mark the footnotes with the number of the verse.  Please see the photo I have posted of the layout I am trying to imitate.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Roble Done. I changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ah, Fran, you are a jewel.  Thank you not only supplying the answer to my question but for helping me with much of the other formatting besides.  I am especially glad that there is a means to automate the verse numbering and reduce human error. I appreciate the suggestion of using enumerated lists to achieve verse numbering, I will try working with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can key your footnotes to Bible verse and chapter numbers in the way you wish using the "paragraph and sentence" annotation features of poemscol. You can place markers for the beginning of each chapter and verse in the margin, and each note (whether endnote or footnote) can begin with the chapter and verse number to which it refers.